# Applying template more than once on an element

Tags: xslt

Im struggling a bit with the following. Given that items may contain several part and spec pairs, i want to process each pair, or apply the template to the item more than once.
Currently, each item is processed once and I'm missing the second part.

```
<figure>
    <list>
        <item>
            <part>
                <p>74174</p>
            </part>
            <spec>
                <u>a1</u>
            </spec>
            <part>
                <p>75375</p>
            </part>
            <spec>
                <u>a4</u>
            </spec>
        </item>
    </list>
</figure>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:if test="$a = 'abc'">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="pt" select="/figure/list/item" />
</xsl:if>

<xsl:template mode="pt" match="item[./part]">
    <xsl:call-template name="ptt">
        <xsl:with-param name="p"><xsl:value-of select="part/p"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="pr">
            <xsl:if test="spec/u">
                <xsl:element name="pr">
                    <xsl:element name="rpn">
                        <xsl:value-of select="spec/u"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="rtn">Alt</xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

I simplified and cropped the code a bit since it goes on and on and on..

Edit: This next one is generating my new elements based solely on the input params

```
<xsl:template name="ptt">
    <xsl:param name="p"/>
    <xsl:param name=u"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You should have a iterable template for `part` and call it inside the `item` template for every `part`.  BTW: it is best to use only relative paths (`select="/figure/list/item"`)

Comment: This question is unclear. **1** because you do not provide enough information (a _representative_ input XML, simplified but preserving the difficulties you are facing, a full XSLT stylesheet). **2** Instead of asking about your attempted solution, explain the _problem_ you'd like to solve. Ideally, this means showing the actual XML output vs. the expected one.

Comment: Can you please supply the expected output and be a bit clear about your requirement

Comment: @Mathias The expected output is a few steps away. But `<xsl:template name="ptt"><xsl:param name="p"/><xsl:param name="pr"/>... ...</xsl:template>` should be called for each pair of part and spec.

Comment: @GermannArlington iterable template: `<xsl:template mode="pt" match="item[./part]"><xsl:for-each select="part[following-sibling::*[1][self::spec]]"><xsl:call-template name="ptt">`

Comment: @Gunnar Never post code in comments, always edit your question instead. Apart from that, it is no use repeating what you said already on templates being called several times. You have to _show_ the XML output you expect.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I'm not looking for an xml output. the ptt template is my interface. many other templates call on this same one, so in the thousand lines of xsl I do not want to change everything, I simply want to feed the right param into this one.

Comment: This question is still unclear. "*i want to process each pair*" is one thing. "*apply the template to the item more than once*" is another. I suggest you decide what the problem is, then post a **minimal** example of the code (XML + XSLT) required to reproduce it, along with the requested output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are unwilling to show a self-contained and complete example (for your future questions, do not make it quite so hard for people to help you), so I am not sure whether the following is helpful to you.

Assuming the XML input you have shown, the stylesheet below demonstrates a way to call a named template for each pair of `spec` and `part` elements, as you requested.

It uses `xsl:for-each-group` (which is exclusive to XSLT 2.0, but you did not tell which version of XSLT you use) to define groups that start with a `part` element, resulting in the said pairs. Then, for each group, the named template `ptt` is invoked with `p` and `u` as parameters.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="part">
            <xsl:call-template name="ptt">
                <xsl:with-param name="p" select="current-group()[1]/p"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="u" select="current-group()[2]/u"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ptt">
        <xsl:param name="p"/>
        <xsl:param name="u"/>

        <result>
            <part><xsl:value-of select="$p"/></part>
            <spec><xsl:value-of select="$u"/></spec>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <part>74174</part>
   <spec>a1</spec>
</result>
<result>
   <part>75375</part>
   <spec>a4</spec>
</result>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well with `call-template` and a parameter `<xsl:with-param name="p"><xsl:value-of select="part/p"/></xsl:with-param>` you are making it harder than it needs to be, assuming XSLT 1.0 the `<xsl:with-param name="p"><xsl:value-of select="part/p"/></xsl:with-param>` fills the parameter `p` with a text node of the string value of the first element selected by `part/p`. So at least use simply `<xsl:with-param name="p-elements" select="part/p"/>`, then the parameter value is a node-set with all `p` elements.

Better yet, simply use template matching and apply-templates consistently, then you don't have to struggle with `call-template` and `with-param`.

Based on your comments you could just use

```
<xsl:template mode="pt" match="item[part]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="part" mode="pt"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="part" mode="pt">
  <xsl:variable name="spec" select="following-sibling::*[1][self::spec]"/>
  ...
</xsl:template>
```